# Can I run watch with a subcommand?

Tags: bash, unix, watch

I'm trying to work out what our build process is doing, and I'm finding it really useful to run this:

```
watch pstree -a $(pgrep -f 'make -k -s')
```

in a terminal.

unfortunately `pgrep -f 'make -k -s'` gets evaluated once and for all, so it needs restarting every time a new build is run.

Is it possible to say to watch, 'run this whole thing every 2secs'

Comment: something like `watch -n2 bash -c 'pstree -a $(pgrep -f "make -k -s")'`?

Comment: they close everything. the trick is to sneak the answer in in the tiny gap between the question and the closure.

Comment: I mean, it's not like trying to work out what a make is doing is a programming question, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me by putting

```
pstree -a $(pgrep -f 'make -k -s')
```

into a file as a little script i.e. testscript.sh

and then running

```
 watch sh testscript.sh
```